# How to align my link to the right side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a link on my index page:

```
<div class="content">
    <a class="buy" href="buy.html">Buy</a> 
</div>
```

I would like to align it to the right side of my page, I tried:

```
a.buy{
  color: #2da1c1;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  left: 252px;
  float: left;

}
a.buy:hover
{
color: #f90;
text-decoration: underline;
left: 252px;
float: left;                 
}
```

But it still located on the left side. (I have included my CSS file in my index.html, and the CSS file already take effect for other elements on the page)

Comment: Normally, when you float things left, they float left, not right.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try `float: right`:

```
a.buy {
    color: #2da1c1;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}
a.buy:hover
{
    color: #f90;
    text-decoration: underline;         
}
```

Another way would be:

```
.content {
    position: relative
}
a.buy {
    color: #2da1c1;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
a.buy:hover
{
    color: #f90;
    text-decoration: underline;         
}
```

Comment: You probably do not need `left:`.

Comment: True. I removed it about 20 seconds after my initial answer.

Answer (score 3):

(1) you have `float: left;` on the example code
(2) maybe if you add `float: right;` to the div it will help?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
a.buy{
  color: #2da1c1;
  font-size: small;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;

}
a.buy:hover
{
color: #f90;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try:

```
.content
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `float: right`, you can change the display property of the link to `block`, since links are `inline` by default:

```
a.buy {
    ...
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
```

You can also use flexbox:

```
a.buy {
    ...
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```